# ERROR 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1242

I have a problem and I dont know how to fix it. I was able to do this query in mysql:

```
UPDATE ARTICULO SET TITULO_ARTICULO= 'La casa' WHERE NUM_ARTICULO='1'
```

But I don't know what happen later than this does'nt work any more and I obtain this error:

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
>   ERROR 1242: 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row

I see other people have this error with nested queries, but anyone with this that is very simple

Thanks!!

**=== EDIT =====**
Yes, I use procedures...but if I a drop my database and reload everything again it works, but then It doesnt..and this error happens in every update that I try to execute over the tables.... this the stored procedure :

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost 
PROCEDURE ART_OBSER(IN numero_art int, IN observaciones varchar(200)) 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE ARTICULO SET TITULO_ARTICULO=observaciones 
    WHERE NUM_ARTICULO=numero_art; 
END $$ 
DELIMITER ; –
```

Comment: it is strange that a simple update statement giving this error. is this update statement executed independently or inside a stored procedure? if so please provide the complete code.

Comment: Yes, I use procedures...but if  I a drop my database and reload everything again it works, but then It doesnt..and this error happens in every update that I try to execute over the tables.... this the  stored procedure :                                                                                                DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ART_OBSER`(IN numero_art int, IN observaciones varchar(200))
BEGIN
UPDATE ARTICULO SET TITULO_ARTICULO=observaciones
WHERE NUM_ARTICULO=numero_art;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: This is all your query? and you dont use subquery ?

Comment: I guess that there is a trigger (or triggers) defined on this table and the error is coming from the trigger fired during the update.

Comment: No I don't use a subquery..... and I don't use triggers on my database